# Select records from a table, which don't exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sqlite, jdbc

I have 2 tables `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` in sqlite DB. TABLE 2 has some of the records of the TABLE1. What I want is to select all the records from TABLE 1, which don't exist in TABLE2. So I coded:

```
String sq = "SELECT TABLE1.name, TABLE1.surname, TABLE1.id FROM TABLE1"
            + "LEFT JOIN TABLE1"
            + "ON TABLE1.id <> TABLE2.id";
```

However this query returns something that i don't get it.. Which is the right query?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN TABLE1` or `TABLE2` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for `NULL`s in second table like:

```
SELECT TABLE1.name, TABLE1.surname, TABLE1.id 
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id
WHERE TABLE2.id IS NULL
```

Alternate solution with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT TABLE1.name, TABLE1.surname, TABLE1.id 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id)
```

One more with `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT TABLE1.name, TABLE1.surname, TABLE1.id 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TABLE1.id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM TABLE2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery to return all id of table 2, now include those ids in table1 which don't exist in table 2.

```
Select name, surname, id from TABLE1 where id not in (Select id from TABLE2)
```